# AzureAD SAML SSO Authentication Time

Tags: azure, session, authentication, single-sign-on, azure-ad-b2b

I would like to know what is the default authentication age that AzureAD is going to give after user authentication.
- Is it should match with the Service Provider Session age
- if it doesn't match any conflict we observe
- what is the best practice to maintain authentication age.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [the official docs here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes) it looks like the default is `until revoked`. As for best practices I generally go with a one hour token and a refresh.

Comment: Agreed - as long as the refresh isn't obtrusive - you can silently refresh.